# Permutation Cycles for work on algebra

Tags: permutation-cycles

What books can I use that focus on permutation cycles? I am working on algebra, particularly on work by Leibniz where he uses the permutation group Sn.

Comment: "The Symmetric Group. Representations, Combinatorial algorithms and symmetric functions" by Bruce Sagan

Comment: But which properties are you looking for ?

Comment: Currently I want to go through permutations as a subject.  But my interest lies in their association with industrial applications.